# Compare and retrieve elements from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, get, compare

I'm trying to build a simple dictionary that compares a string to a word on the `ArrayList` and then returns a different value from the list. The `ArrayList` is laid out with the foreign word and then followed by the English equivalent so the idea is that I type in a word, use scanner to compare it to the array list and then return the index value +1 so if the word I type is 7th on the list, I want it to return the 8th word and print it out.

I've got the basic idea of inputting a string and comparing it, but I don't know how to return the following word from the `ArrayList`:

```
public void translateWords(){
        String nameSearch;
        nameSearch=input.nextLine();

        for (Phrase c:phrases) {
            if (c.getName().equals(nameSearch))  {
                System.out.println( c.advancedToString());      
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("not on list");
```

I've tried playing about with the get method for the ArrayList but I'm unsure on how to use it so any feedback would be very appreciated here.

Comment: If you want to create a dictionary, why not use a [dictionary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)?

Comment: You could do the loop the old way (i.e. using a integer counter) and then calling phrases.get(i+1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for-each` is not appropriate in this case because you can not access successive elements, in your case translated words.
So I suggest you to use `Iterate`

I suppose `phrases` is of type `List<Phrase>`

```
public void translateWords(){
        String nameSearch;
        nameSearch=input.nextLine();

        Iterator<Phrase> it = phrases.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
           Phrase c = it.next();
           if (c.getName().equals(nameSearch))  {
                System.out.println( it.next().advancedToString());      
                return;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("not on list");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this one works a treat. It does exactly what I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this do the job for you? Not tested, just from my head:

```
public void translateWords(){
    String nameSearch;
    nameSearch=input.nextLine();

    if(c.indexof(nameSearch)){
        System.out.println(c.get(c.indexof(c.indexof(nameSearch)+1));
    } else {
        System.out.println("not on list");
    }
}
```

Comment: `indexOf` won't work this way, since it is a list of Phrases, not of Strings.

Comment: Moreover, the code is pretty wrong... The line `c.get(c.indexof(c.indexof(nameSearch)+1)` will try to get the index of... an index? Also, parentheses do not match. Drop the second `indexOf(`. Still, `indexOf` is called unnecessarily often, and won't work in the first place (see previous comment).

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use a dictionary, e.g., a Java [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). Without knowing how your `Phrase` class is implemented, this might look like this:

```
// create dictionary
Map<Phrase, Phrase> d = new HashMap<Phrase, Phrase>();
// add phrases
d.put(new Phrase("Guten Tag", "de"), new Phrase("Good morning", "en"));
// get translation
Phrase p = d.get(new Phrase(nameSearch, "de"));
```

(To make this work, `Phrase.equals` and `Phrase.hashCode` have to be [implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27581/1639625).)

This seems to be a better choice of data structure for your task. Using a HashMap, lookup times for items are *O(1)*, as opposed to *O(n)* in your approach, which could be relevant if your dictionary contains thousands or millions of phrases, or if you have to do this very often. A possible downside is that the entries have to be really equal, e.g. you could not (easily) check for "similar" phrases or words.